# Is this set open?

Tags: general-topology

Let $$C=\{z\in \mathbb C, {\rm Re}(z^2)=25 \}$$

Is $C$ open or closed?

I am a little confused here. I think the set should be open and closed, because since the imaginary part has not been defined, the set can include the entire complex plane, when ${\rm Re}(z)=-5,5$. Is my reasoning true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $C$ is closed because it is of the form $\{z \in \Bbb C \mid f(z) = g(z)  \}$ with $f(z) = {\rm Re}(z^2)$ and $g \equiv 25$ continuous functions and $\Bbb C$ Hausdorff. Since $\Bbb C$ is connected, $C$ can't be open too.

Maybe you'll want to check for yourself that $z \mapsto {\rm Re}(z^2)$ is continuous and that if $X, Y$ are topological spaces, with $Y$ Hausdorff, and $f,g\colon X \to Y$ are continuous, then $\{x \in X \mid f(x) = g(x)\}$ is closed.

Comment: Isn't it sufficient (without mentioning it is  Hausdorff) to say that $\{25\}$ is closed, and that $C = f^{-1}(\{25\})$ (where $f$ is indeed continuous)?

Comment: I have not sufficient knowledge of Hausdorff spaces

Comment: You're using that $\Bbb C$ is at least $T_1$ to ensure that $\{25\}$ is closed. Since $g \equiv 25$ is constant, Hausdorffness is overkill. $T_1$ is enough.

Comment: @IvoTerek Can you please explain this without using Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: It really looks to me that the question doesn't require that much to argue that $\{25\}$ is closed. I may be wrong, but this doesn't look like the type of questions where one has to argue that a singleton in $\mathbb{C}$ is a closed set -- I would take that as a given, any day. (But again, then the tag <general-topology> may have been a bad choice from the OP's side.)

Comment: Ok. Take a sequence $(z_n)_{n \geq 1} \subseteq \Bbb C$ with $z_n \to z$. Then ${\rm Re}(z_n^2) = 25$ for all $n \geq 1$. So: $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} {\rm Re}(z_n^2) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} 25 \implies {\rm Re}(z^2) = 25,$$and $z \in C$. So $C$ is closed.

Comment: @Clement yeah, I saw the <general-topology> tag and thought that maybe pointing the details would help.

Comment: @IvoTerek agreed, there is a discrepancy between the tag chosen and the tone of the question (and the comments). (I'm also a bit confused trying to parse Alec Teal's comment -- is it saying that continuity + singleton closed is enough, or that is is not?)

Comment: @Jennie Look at this another approach, maybe you'll like it more. Suppose that $z \not\in C$. So ${\rm Re}(z^2) \neq 25$, and by continuity there is $r> 0$ such that ${\rm Re}(w^2) \neq 25$ for all $w \in B(z, r)$. So $z \in B(z,r) \subseteq \Bbb C \setminus C$, and so $\Bbb C \setminus C$ is open. We conclude that $C$ is closed. Better?